# Cordova wrong icon in "Siri App Suggestions"

Tags: ios, cordova

I have set every possible icon into my own one, and it is OK everywhere,
 **except for one place** - in the Siri Suggestions:

[image: wrong icon]

Can anyone please tell which of the icons affects this icon? I was spending hours trying to solve it!

Here is my config.xml:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <icon height="180" src="myres/icon/ios/Icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
    <icon height="60" src="myres/icon/ios/Icon-60.png" width="60" />
    <icon height="120" src="myres/icon/ios/Icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="76" src="myres/icon/ios/Icon-76.png" width="76" />
    <icon height="152" src="myres/icon/ios/Icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
    <icon height="40" src="myres/icon/ios/Icon-40.png" width="40" />
    <icon height="80" src="myres/icon/ios/Icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
    <icon height="57" src="myres/icon/ios/Icon.png" width="57" />
    <icon height="114" src="myres/icon/ios/Icon@2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon height="72" src="myres/icon/ios/Icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon height="144" src="myres/icon/ios/Icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon height="167" src="myres/icon/ios/Icon-167.png" width="167" />
    <icon height="29" src="myres/icon/ios/Icon-small.png" width="29" />
    <icon height="58" src="myres/icon/ios/Icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
    <icon height="167" src="myres/icon/ios/Icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
    <icon height="87" src="myres/icon/ios/Icon-29@3x.png" width="87" />
    <icon height="50" src="myres/icon/ios/Icon-50.png" width="50" />
    <icon height="100" src="myres/icon/ios/Icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
    <! skipping splash entries !-->
</platform>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apple outlines the appropriate sizes in several places, like their [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/app-icon/), and [this technical document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1686/_index.html). You can reference that and see what's going on. You probably want to look for the Spotlight image size.

This is a good example of why it pays to write native apps in Xcode using one of Apple's first class languages.

**Edit:**

Searching StackOverflow for the same problem shows that Cordova seems to have an issue with copying icons correctly. See these questions, where the suggested solution was to modify the Xcode project directly:

- [PhoneGap iOS App Icon [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17828920/phonegap-ios-app-icon?rq=1)
- [App icon not changing to custom icon using cordova [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17999766/app-icon-not-changing-to-custom-icon-using-cordova?rq=1)

Both of those are marked as dupes of this one, which has a lot more information:

- [How to add app icon within phonegap projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17820492/how-to-add-app-icon-within-phonegap-projects)

Comment: In this case, using a third party layer on top of the supported system makes it more complicated to debug small things. Instead of a single point of failure (your Swift or Objective-C code) you now have two points of failure: (your code, or Cordova.) It's not clear to me if an icon is missing from the XML, or if Cordova is doing the wrong thing with the XML file. With Xcode, I can rely on Apple's tooling to put the icon in the right place with more confidence. So using a third party tool just makes your life more difficult.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Moshe. However your closing statement is weird. Of course it 'pays' to write native apps, but this way you miss the fantastic *Cordova* advantage of writing easily in JavaScript for both iOS and Android at once. I'm developing native apps for several years as my main job, and still prefer Cordova for my private projects.

Comment: This is *not* a correct answer, because the docs specify 80x80 and 120x120 for spotlight sizes, and these sizes are already specified in my config.xml

Comment: @Moshe, but in this case it's an icon missing, it has nothing to do with code. Even if it's a bug in Cordova that doesn't copy that icon for some reason, he can still open the Xcode project and manually add the image as you would do in your native project, so you last sentence makes no sense in this answer.

Comment: @jcesarmobile Cordova isn’t just the code. A platform is the entire experience. If a toolchain doesn’t deliver on what it offers, you’re better off looking elsewhere.