# Generating iOS and Android icons in Cordova / PhoneGap

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I have a freshly created Cordova project with the following `config.xml` setup (used the instructions from http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/config_ref_images.md.html). I also added 2 platforms (iOS and Android).

When I run either `cordova run ios` or `cordova run android`, the project still has the default Cordova icons. My understanding from the documentation is that Corodva is supposed to create the icons automatically based in the `icon.png` I supplied in the `config.xml`.

`config.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.testapp" version="1.1.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>SingleApp</name>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
  <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
  <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
  <preference name="Fullscreen" value="false" />
  <preference name="target-device" value="handset" />

  <description>
      A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
  </description>
  <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
      Apache Cordova Team
  </author>
  <content src="index.html" />
  <access origin="*" />

  <icon src="icon.png" />

</widget>
```

Comment: in Cordova 5.1.1, the icons does not work well! Check my answer here to know everything you should know about icons: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31674547/82609

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I wrote a script that auto generates icons for cordova using ImageMagick:

https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-icon

To use it, create an "icon.png" file and place it in the root folder of your project, then run:

```
cordova-icon
```

and it will generate all the required icons for the platforms your project has.

You can also configure it as a hook in your cordova project so the icons will be generated every time you build the project based on the icon.png you've added. (instructions in the readme).

Comment: Thank you @Alex for sharing that script, it's perfect :-)

Comment: This works great. Thanks Alex. He's also got one for [splash screens](https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-splash).

Comment: @Alex ,keepitreal: Will this override config.xml specification for slpashscreen?

Comment: Great script!  Thank you.
I did get one error:
Cordova 5.1 output :
Generating Icons for android

  ✓  drawable-ldpi/icon.png created
  ✓  drawable-mdpi/icon.png created
  ✓  drawable-hdpi/icon.png created
  ✓  drawable-xhdpi/icon.png created
{ [Error: Command failed: convert: unable to open image `platforms/android/res/drawable/icon.png': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2709.
convert: WriteBlob Failed `platforms/android/res/drawable/icon.png' @ error/png.c/MagickPNGErrorHandler/1645.
] timedOut: false, killed: false, code: 1, signal: null }

Comment: some buggy stuff, had the same error as above. Also it doesn't update config.xml, am I right? "ionic resource" supposed to do the trick but also hangs

Answer (score 14):

If you are using cordova 3.5.0 they have updated the docs. In older versions i've always had to replace the icons manually in the project but the latest version of cordova is working fine.

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/config_ref_images.md.html#Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens

As you can see here https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli/issues/58 it's been a common problem. So if you are using an older version of cordova i recommend to update it with the command `npm update -g cordova`

And after that you should update your config.xml to something like this:

```
    <icon src="www/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/icon.png" />
    <platform name="android">
          <icon src="www/res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png" density="ldpi" />
          <icon src="www/res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png" density="mdpi" />
          <icon src="www/res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png" density="hdpi" />
          <icon src="www/res/drawable-xhdpi/icon.png" density="xhdpi" />
    </platform>

    <platform name="ios">
              <!-- iOS 7.0+ -->
              <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
              <icon src="www/res/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60" />
              <icon src="www/res/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120" />
              <!-- iPad -->
              <icon src="www/res/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76" />
              <icon src="www/res/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152" />
              <!-- iOS 6.1 -->
              <!-- Spotlight Icon -->
              <icon src="www/res/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40" />
              <icon src="www/res/ios/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80" />
              <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch -->
              <icon src="www/res/ios/icon.png" width="57" height="57" />
              <icon src="www/res/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114" />
              <!-- iPad -->
              <icon src="www/res/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72" />
              <icon src="www/res/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144" />
              <!-- iPhone Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
              <icon src="www/res/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29" />
              <icon src="www/res/ios/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" height="58" />
              <!-- iPad Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
              <icon src="www/res/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50" />
              <icon src="www/res/ios/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100" />
     </platform>
```

As you can see the URIs are relative to the cordova project's path, not to the www folder.

Comment: Do you know if this will then package the app with all of the assets still contained in the projects `www` folder? If so, this causes bloat in the app package. Just wondering if that was addressed with this new rollout?

Comment: yes you can create a folder outside the www/ with the images and address them from the config.xml file, the folder can be even outside the cordova project folder. Ex: "../Image_folder"

Comment: if you put it inside the www folder it will package the app with the images inside, if you locate them outside the package it won't increase in size.

Comment: Cordova Team should really consider fixing they documents and samples, most of them are useless and even confusing!

Thank you

Answer (score 8):

The `config.xml` settings for icons only works with the PhoneGap Build service. After adding both of your platforms you need to manually (or you can create a hook, but I haven't done that myself) place your icons in the correct paths.

For iOS:

```
PROJECT_PATH/platforms/ios/PROJECT_NAME/Resources/icons
```

For Android:

```
PROJECT_PATH/platforms/android/res/drawable
```

Android has many `res/drawable-*` folders, use as applies to your app but at minimum add to `res/drawable`

Then run `cordova prepare` or `build` or `run`

Comment: Is this still the case?  It feels like it was something that was addressed a long time ago...

Comment: Not sure, this was 3 years ago. Haven't been active with cordova for a few years now.

Answer (score 8):

If you are willing to install extra software for icon generation you can use Ionic which has such function.

Do the following:

1. `npm install ionic -g`
2. Put png, psd or .ai files for icons and/or splashscreens to `${project_location}/resources`
3. `ionic resources`

If you want to generate icons only there is a handy key for that:

```
ionic resources --icon
```

More details [here](http://ionicframework.com/blog/automating-icons-and-splash-screens/)

Comment: works but images are too bug, i have a 80Kb image and it created a total of 12 Mb, I guess I better save them manually

Comment: ionic uses `cordova-res` under the hood https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-res, it might be enough if you don't want to install ionic

Comment: It was mentioned in answers

Answer (score 2):

Don't you need to specify the folder that has the icon on it? Cordova replaces the icon with the default one when it is not found.

Have you tried to replace with something like:

```
<icon src="res/icon.png" />
```

Comment: in Cordova 5.1.1, the icons does not work well! Your answer won't work for Android. Check my answer here to know everything you should know about icons: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31674547/82609

Answer (score 2):

`npm install -g cordova-res`

then `cordova-res`

also supports adaptive icons for android

Answer (score 0):

Try following https://www.npmjs.org/package/cordova-gen-icon

Example:

```
$ cordova create hello com.example.hello
Creating a new cordova project with name "HelloCordova" and id "com.example.hello" at location "hello"
$ cd hello
$ cordova platform add ios
Creating ios project...
Preparing ios project
$ cordova-gen-icon 
Generate cordova icons with
project: .
icon   : ./www/img/logo.png
target : 

generate iOS icons
Success generate icon set
```

Answer (score 0):

A little explication for people who say `<icon src="res/icon.png" />` Not work !

You must put icon.png in both this folders

> project_name/res/

and

> project_name/platforms/platform_name/res/

Steps:

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
cd hello
```

Copy your icon.png to `project_name/res/`
Open `config.xml` and put `<icon src="res/icon.png" />`

After that run

```
cordova platform add android
```

Now copy your icon.png to ... `hello/platforms/android/res/`

then

```
cordova build android
```

and finally

```
adb install  platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
```

After that you  can see on device your app with your icon

Answer (score 0):

Please upload your icon here: https://pgicons.abiro.com/

You can easily get all things from one station, like Icons(All Platforms), Splash Screens(All Platforms), config.xml (with generated icon name and path).

You just need to replace the `res` folder and update `config.xml`, nothing else.