# Cordova / PhoneGap 3.4.0 Splash screen / default icon

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

Please do not tell me what to do with xcode because while I do have a great respect for those sexy MacBook pros, they are out of my price range and I use a PC.  I use NotePad++

and I compile internally on my PC.  Of course, I have the latest PhoneGap and Cordova.

I tried everything I can to change the default icon to something else, but it still gives me the default icon, and I learned that config.xml is irrelevant if I am compiling internally

Is there any way to work around it?  Do you recommend the "hook"?

Or compile online on Adobe website?

Thanks a lot for your help, experts on Stack Overflow.

Comment: possible duplicate of [generating ios and android icons in cordova / phonehap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23830467/generating-ios-and-android-icons-in-cordova-phonehap)

Comment: Care to describe just how in the world are you compiling an iOS app locally on a non-OSX machine? The only supported method is to have a Mac with OSX. (Honestly, get a Mac Mini. They work just fine, and aren't that pricey. Or rent one online.)

Answer (score 0):

I think documentation is clearly stated what you should do for android and ios. Besides as far as i know you can not compile (offline) for ios without having a mac.

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/config_ref_images.md.html#Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens

Comment: First of all I am using Cordova 3.5.0 not 3.4.0 and I have been looking at the Apache Cordova Website since 10 hours ago~~

Comment: Well, looks like the issue you mentioned is solved with 3.5.0. Is there any specific reason to not upgrading your cordova version ?

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2606

Also other changes can be seen here:

http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2014/05/23/cordova-350.html

Sadly 3.5.0 is dropping support for ios 5.0. This is the only big con that i can see.