# Cordova - run app in device and icon

Tags: android, cordova, icons

When I run

```
cordova run android
```

in my cordova project, it installs ok the app in the device. But the icon used is still the default one from cordova, not the one defined in config.xml (in the root folder 
For testing, I changed all the original icon.png in /platforms/android/res folders, changing it to the one I want, but the installed app still uses the old one.

Is this the normal behaviour? When the final .apk is built, the package will use the right icon? Or is this my fault?
Running cordova 3.5

UPDATE: found the answer here [Generating iOS and Android icons in Cordova / PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23830467/generating-ios-and-android-icons-in-cordova-phonegap)
Using the module https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-icon help to copy icons to th write folder(s)

Comment: Customising icons in config.xml is only for phonegap build. Changing it in platforms/android is the correct way. Maybe try to uninstall the app from the phone and re-install it.