# Best practice for icon and splashscreen with phonegap

Tags: cordova, build, icons, splash-screen

We are using cordova CLI interface(3.5.0) to build locally as well as phonegap build in the cloud to build easily for all platforms. I feel like this is complicated to have an efficient build process that works well for both building interfaces.

Please correct me if I am wrong or suggest me something better to manage Icon and SplashScreen for both local and remote builds

### 1. Local builds

We use cordova tool to build our application for iOS and Android. According to the [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/config_ref_images.md.html)

#### Icons:

> When working in the CLI you can define app icon(s) via  element
>   (config.xml).
>
> ```
> <icon src="res/ios/icon.png" platform="ios" width="57" height="57"
> density="mdpi" />
> ```

#### SplashScreen:

Again, according to the [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/config_ref_images.md.html):

> Use the Splashscreen API to enable display of an app's introductory
>   splash screen on many platforms. When working in the CLI, splash
>   screen source files are located within the project's www/res/screens
>   subdirectory.

It clearly mention  www/res/screens folder, but just below it says the following:

> Place 9-patch image files in the Android project's
>   platforms/android/res/drawable* directories.

### 2. Phonegap builds(in the cloud)

For phonegap build, it seems fairly easy, we just add some tag in the config.xml, and put all our icons/splashscreen in res/icon/{platform} folder

```
 <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
```

### Questions

#### Local build / Icons

Do they mean www/res folder or platform/android/res folder ?
If it is in platform, it means that i need some kind of hooks to copy icons in the correct folder [like this](http://devgirl.org/2013/11/12/three-hooks-your-cordovaphonegap-project-needs/) as I want to have my icons and splashscreen into my source control. Is there some kind of best practice?

#### Local build / SplashScreen

Can you please clarify if it is www/res or platform/android/res/drawable ?

#### phonegap build

Am i correct ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating iOS and Android icons in Cordova / PhoneGap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23830467/generating-ios-and-android-icons-in-cordova-phonegap)

Comment: Thanks but still really confusing in my point of view. I was hoping for a clear answer and best practices