# iOS splash screen images not copying over

Tags: ios, cordova

I am creating a PhoneGap project and I have a config as follows:

```
<icon src="icon.png" />

<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />

<icon gap:platform="ios" height="57" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="72" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="114" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="144" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />

<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />

<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="320" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-landscape.jpg" width="480" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="768" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.jpg" width="1024" />
```

For some unknown reason when performing `phonegap build ios` the splash images are not being copied across into the platform resources.

For reference. I am using version 4.1.2

Thanks.

Comment: Those config setting are only for use with the PhoneGap Build online service. For local builds you need place the files yourself. See this answer for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23830467/generating-ios-and-android-icons-in-cordova-phonegap/23917490#23917490

Comment: @DawsonLoudon so icons are supported by local build, but splashes are not? Because the icons are happily copying over for me, just not the splashes. And the referenced answer only says icons.

Comment: No, the solution on the other page is for both icons and splashscreens. But what you found below must be newer (that used to not work), good find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my own solution to this.
As I was building this locally via `phonegap build (ios|android)` and not online my build tool was just a wrapper of cordova. Because of this I decided to try use cordova's syntax for this situation instead. It worked.

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/config_ref_images.md.html