# Errors running android emulator from command line

Tags: cordova, android-emulator

I'm working on a mobile app that is created using phonegap. Instead of IDE I'm using the command-line to run the android emulator.

This is my project structure,

[image]

On running the emulator it shows up but I see couple of errors in the console.

[image]

I don't have the files `icon.png` and the other one in the `src` folder. Instead of looking those things in the `www` folder it is some-way referring in the `src`. I've no clue why. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You need to run cordova/phonegap commands from the project folder i.e D:\Personal\Safe\src

Comment: You mean I need to run the "cordova emulate android" from D:\Personal\Safe?

Comment: Yes if that is your project folder.

Comment: D:\Personal\Safe\src is the project folder. I still see the errors if I run from there.

Comment: which directory did you create the project? How did you create the project? The screen shows Project is **"Safe"** so `D:\...\Safe\src` cannot be the project directory. It has to be `D:\...\Safe`

Comment: I run the command "cordova create src com.prideparrot.safe Safe" from the folder D:\Personal\Safe. So I thought all the phonegap components will exists in the src folder.

Comment: I got the answer from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17820492/how-to-add-app-icon-within-phonegap-projects