# Where to put android icon file in Cordova 3.5?

Tags: android, cordova

I have created an android app with Cordova 3.5 and it compiles and runs OK, and I get the splash screen I want. But the app icon just stays as the default Cordova icon, in spite of me copying my own icon to everywhere/anywhere I think it should go.
The correct icons (simply called icon.png) are in these folders:

```
....\my_project\platforms\android\res\drawable\icon.png
....\my_project\platforms\android\res\drawable-ldpi\icon.png
```

...etc, and also here:

```
....\my_project\www\res\icons\android\icon-36-ldpi.png
....\my_project\www\res\icons\android\icon-48-ldpi.png
```

...etc. I've manually copied and renamed the icons from the 'www' folder to the android platforms folder, although I don't think that should be necessary.
When I view any of these icons in Windows explorer they appear as my own icon; but still in the app on my device the original Cordova icon is shown. I've read all the posts I can find about this and have failed to find a solution.

[later]
Please ignore my own comment below; the correct icon now appears with the debug version but not with the (alpha) release downloaded from Play Store. Any ideas?

Comment: HaHa! something I did in checking and writing this post appears to have done the trick, justa  few minutes after posting. Not sure what it was, so I'd still be grateful for any help with the correct method for setting up these icons.

Answer (score 0):

Check my FAQ here https://stackoverflow.com/a/31674547/82609

You can put the icons anywhere inside the cordova project and it must be relative to the root. So if you put the icons in `www`, the path must include `www`.

You don't have to use `res` or `drawable-*` in the path you use with Cordova: just put them where you want to.

Note that currently (5.1.1) declaring an icon without density seems to be ignored for Android platform