# Cordova 3.4 Splashscreen not working

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen

I have an Android Phonegap proyect and I'm trying to use the Splashscreen plugin Cordova provides. I think I have everything correctly set... Here are the pieces of code I think are relevant.

**Config.xml**

```
<widget ...>
    ...
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="15000" />
    <plugin name="SplashScreen" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>
</widget>
```

**Index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    function onDeviceReady() {
        navigator.splashscreen.hide()
    }
</script>
```

I have correctly installed with the CLI the plugin and the splash itself is in the res/drawable* folders in the Android project as I think it should be, but regardless of what I try to do, the splash is not showing. Not even a default one. Not even if I disable the navigator.splashscreen.hide() function (in case it was too fast).

I'm absolutely lost now, have been trying tweaks for a week but I just can't see it.

Comment: It's far fetched but did you install the splashscreen plugin?

Comment: Yes, I did, from the command line interface. And everything looked "o.k."...Even a new package appears in the src folder in eclipse called "org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" with a single java file that seems correct to me. No errors in the eclipse enviroment. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8):

I'm using cordova v3.6.3 in my android project.

I read a API & Plugin Documentations but, I confused the some options in config.
but, I found a perfect solution.

**1. above all, you don't need to use 
    "navigator.splashscreen.hide()" or ".show()" in Android project.**

**2. refer my directory structure for understanding clearly.**

[image]

**3. Add following codes into your config.xml file.**
     ※ Do not change the value="screen". 
        you just change the src and delay value for your splashscreen image.

**[Config.xml]**

```
<platform name="android">
    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-default.png" />
</platform>
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="4000" />
```

**4. delete a "screen.png" file from drawable directory for understanding clearly.**

[image]

**5. build your project on your command line (cordova build android)
 and, look again drawable directory.**

I'll promise, you'll success. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for this. The only clear answer I found so far.

Comment: @VenkatKotra read mine here. You don't need any manual process but should always include a density: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31674547/82609

Comment: Thx, saved me a lot of headache!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue after the 2.5.1 CLI update. If i run the same project in the VisualStudio ionic simulator all works fine. It also works fine when I run the app in the bowser with Telerik Platform. I just need to comment out navigator.splashscreen.hide(); in my project for the latest CLI simulator or I just get a plain white screen.
James