# how to change a app icon in cordova development for ios

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

i have got exactly this kind of error while tring to change my app icon and also i have tried some stackoverflow links but it would not workout for me . please find some answer thanks in advance

CompileAssetCatalog build/emulator/shiningKnight.app shiningKnight/Images.xcassets

> Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args:
>   -xcconfig,/Users/sritharan/Documents/shiningKnight/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,shiningKnight.xcodeproj,-target,shiningKnight,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS
>   Simulator,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/sritharan/Documents/shiningKnight/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/sritharan/Documents/shiningKnight/platforms/ios/build/sharedpc

Answer (score 0):

this is how to change a cordoca app icon : https://cordova.apache.org/docs/fr/latest/config_ref/images.html

> [How to add app icon within phonegap projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17820492/how-to-add-app-icon-within-phonegap-projects)

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by using these steps as-

1. To create Icon-

---

```
<icon src="icon.png" /> or 
<icon src="icon-60@3x.png" platform="ios" width="180" height="180" />
```

2. To create splash-

---

```
<splash src="splash/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
```

For more details we can just [see here](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/icons-and-splash/)