# How can i change this App Icon in config.xml?

Tags: android, phonegap-build, phonegap-desktop-app

[image: PhoneGap Icon]

How can i change this PhoneGap App Icon marked in the picture?

Comment: Maybe this link helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17820492/how-to-add-app-icon-within-phonegap-projects

Comment: Are you building it locally or using phonegap.build service?

Answer (score 0):

Add an icon in the www root folder (say icon.png) and add this line in your config.xml file:

```
<icon src="icon.png" />
```

It is recommended to provided several icons for different resolutions and different platforms, but the above line will get you started.

For example, to provided icons for iOS devices, you can add something like:

```
<icon src="icon.png" />
<platform name="ios">
  <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon.png" width="57" height="57" />
  <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114" />
  <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72" />
  <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144" />
  <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60" />
  <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120" />
  <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180" />
  <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76" />
  <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152" />
</platform>
```

Those paths are relative to the www root.