# Cordova 3.3.0 Android icon doesn't update in app manager

Tags: android, cordova, icons, android-manifest

I have updated the icons like it says to do [here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.2.0/config_ref_images.md.html) on Cordova for Android.

It updates the icon fine on the menu screen:

[image]

But then when you press settings -> apps it displays the Cordova icon:

[image]

*appoligies for the poor screenshots there was an issue with the tablet*.

I have had a look on the web, but I cant find anything related to this!

Anyone else got this problem / found a solution?

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hi paste your icon in drawable folder. And change this line in your **Manifest.xml** file

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
```

[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15018098/phonegap-android-how-to-force-application-to-use-icons-from-asset-www-res-inste)

and enjoy

Comment: When I add "@drawable/ic_launcher" I get
`Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/ic_launcher'). AndroidManifest.xml /ShowMeWhere line 5 Android AAPT Problem
`

Comment: wts your icon name ? ic_launcher ah?

Comment: change ic_launcher to ur icon name for example your icon name home_icon.png means you need to change @drawable/home_icon like this